# How to fix git fatal error with strange characters when pushing?

Tags: git

I installed git and created new repository on github. then I opened my project and started copy and paste commands from github. befere that I had added github username and email globally. when I paste the last command(git push) I had to authorize my account. I did it and than vscode asked me to authorize one more time. I did it. And than I got this error in console:

```
fatal: ╨Ч╨░╨┐╤А╨╛╤Б ╨▒╤Л╨╗ ╨┐╤А╨╡╤А╨▓╨░╨╜: ╨Э╨╡ ╤Г╨┤╨░╨╗╨╛╤Б╤М ╤Б╨╛╨╖╨┤╨░╤В╤М ╨╖╨░╤Й╨╕╤Й╨╡╨╜╨╜╤Л╨╣ ╨║╨░╨╜╨░╨╗ SSL/TLS.
fatal: ╨Я╤А╨╛╨╕╨╖╨╛╤И╨╗╨░ ╨╛╤И╨╕╨▒╨║╨░ ╨┐╤А╨╕ ╨╛╤В╨┐╤А╨░╨▓╨║╨╡ ╨╖╨░╨┐╤А╨╛╤Б╨░.
```

if I try to repeat this then the authorization window does not open in my browser(just empty page) and I get the same error

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong, but what's the default character encoding on your terminal emulator?

Comment: What language are you using, Russian? This looks like an encoding problem, and there are lots of Cyrillic characters in there.

Comment: Are you using some non-Latin encoding / language?

Comment: Found it: it's Russian, encoded as CP 866 but decoded as UTF-8. `fatal: Запрос был прерван: Не удалось создать защищенный канал SSL/TLS.
fatal: Произошла ошибка при отправке запроса.`

Comment: Oops, I got that backwards: it's encoded as UTF-8 but decoded as CP 866.

Comment: @wjandrea Nice detective work; I played with it for a bit but failed to crack it.

Comment: @matt Thanks :) If it helps, I figured it out because the pattern looks like a multi-byte encoding interpreted as a single-byte encoding, plus OP's name and the characters used look East Slavic. So I just looked for relatively old Russian encodings. I tried CP 1251 first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [wjandrea's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73177025/how-to-fix-git-fatal-error-with-strange-characters-when-pushing#comment129238695_73177025), the error messages are the Russian translation of:

```
The request was aborted: Failed to create secure channel SSL/TLS
```

and:

```
An error occurred while sending the request
```

which are actually libcurl errors, rather than Git errors (see, e.g., [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/825110/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssltls-se-2.html)).

Your options are therefore to fix whatever is causing libcurl to be unable to set up SSL/TLS, or to use an ssh URL instead of an `https://`-based URL.